# How to change parameter value in XML using bash or perl?

Tags: xml, perl

I have a xml in below and need to modify some parameter value

```
<test name="MyRawExample" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="example-parameter" value="11111" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.ericol.nco.blocktests.example.ExampleTestcase" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

I need to look for a specific parameter name and then replace the corresponding value by a new input value and updates the xml file.

I was wondering if anybody can help me how I may change it or offer me a rigid doc so that i can find the most efficient script to accomplish this.

Regards,
Behzad

Comment: This is not how stackoverflow works. You show us what you've got coded so far, ask about a particular problem you're encountering, and we try to help. We don't write your scripts for you.

Comment: for instance look up pratameter name "example-parameter" and then change corresponding value tag with 22222.

Comment: I was trying sth like below but I have not any reference so that I can polish it to fit into my desired results: awk -F"=" -v newval=22222 '/parameter/{$2=newval;print;next}1' src/main/resources/exampleSuite.xml

Answer (score 6):

As Mortiz mentioned, you should first make some effort to solve the problem.

With that in mind, gave a look at the [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTwig) Perl module. It will enable you do do what you want easily.

UPDATE: Since you've done some work and came up with some code, here's a working solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig=XML::Twig->new(   
    twig_handlers => { 
        parameter  => sub {
            if ($_->att('name') eq 'example-parameter') {
                $_->set_att('value' => '22222') 
            }
        }
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
);

$twig->parsefile('src/main/resources/exampleSuite.xml');
$twig->flush;
```

I'll leave it to you to do the file replacement.

Comment: I tried the following but I got strange results :s #! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print  => 'indented',
    twig_handlers => { 
        name => sub { 
            $_->set_text( 'example-parameter' )->flush  if $_->text eq 'exampleparameter' 
        },
    },
)->parsefile_inplace( 'src/main/resources/exampleSuite.xml', '*_bak' );

Comment: Can you please offer me some tutorial how did you make it?! I need do more scripting tasks. Thanks

Comment: I did the following for the file replacement but when I pass ab argument as the output path it does bot work while as I enter the explicit path it works.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use XML::Twig;
my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $twig=XML::Twig->new(   
    twig_handlers => { 
        parameter  => sub {
            if ($_->att('name') eq 'example-parameter') {
                $_->set_att('value' => '22222') 
            }
        }
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
);

$twig->parsefile($file);
open XMLOUT, $file;
$twig->print(\*XMLOUT) or
die "Failed to write modified XML file:$!\n";
close XMLOUT;
$twig->flush();

Comment: Please [contact me offline](http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/about) for personalized tutorials/consulting services.

Comment: enter code here
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use XML::Twig;
my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $twig=XML::Twig->new(   
twig_handlers => { 
    parameter  => sub {
        if ($_->att('name') eq 'example-parameter') {
            $_->set_att('value' => '22222') 
        }
    }
},
pretty_print => 'indented',
);
$twig->parsefile($file);
open XMLOUT, $file;
$twig->print(\*XMLOUT) or
die "Failed to write modified XML file:$!\n";
close XMLOUT;
$twig->flush();

Comment: as you see the code above it doesn't work but if I put an explicit path on XMLOUT then it works!

Comment: If have tried Twig perl module but my I have to follow perl core module! my $twig=XML::Twig->new(   
    twig_handlers => { 
        parameter  => sub {
            if ($_->att('name') eq 'example-parameter') {
                $_->set_att('value' => $PORT) 
            }
        }
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
);

$twig->parsefile($file);

Comment: Can anyone tell the equivalent script using core module?!